# How to express subset relations as a morphism in a category?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, morphism

Given two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \subset B$ What morphism do I use to express this relation in a category of sets.

Is it $ i : A \to B$ where $i$ is the inclusion map?
or $ pr : B \to A$ where $pr$ is the projection map that "forgets" $B-A$?

Also what is the relation of those two maps? Are they inverse to each other?
If not what is the inverse map of $i$?

Comment: You use the inclusion to represent subsets. They are only partial inverses to each other, so that $pr\circ i=id$ but not $i\circ pr$. Neither of these have a full inverse unless they are bijections.

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you talking of the category of sets or of a generic category? Besides, what do you mean by projection $\mathrm{pr} \colon B \to A$? If $A \subseteq B$ there is not a canonical definition of such a function.

Answer (score 2):

The generalisation of "subset" in a category is given by the concept of a [subobject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject), which is a collection of monomorphisms $A \rightarrowtail B$ intuitively sharing the same image in $B$. In the category of sets, a subobject corresponds to a subset up to isomorphism (if $A$ is an actual subset of $B$, and $A'$ is isomorphic to $A$, we still want to count $A'$ as a subset of $B$). Every inclusion $i : A \hookrightarrow B$ identifies a subobject.

For the second part of your question, projection maps are not unique: perhaps you could clarify what map $B \to A$ you are considering? An inclusion $i : A \hookrightarrow B$ does not generally have an inverse (though there is a natural inverse image function $i^{-1} : B \to \mathcal P(A)$).